# Attempting to get image preview set up in Ranger, and having an issue with images appearing off-screen

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, images, ranger

So I am attempting to get image preview setup in ranger with WezTerm on a WSL2 install of Arch. I've got images showing with imgcat:

[image: Imgcat]

But I am having an issue where ranger is just shoving everything off the side of the screen:

[image: Offscreen?!]

I've checked github for ranger and wezterm, as well as done some googling as well, but I can't seem to find anything other than basic "image no work, what do?!" type posts or mentions of setting iterm2_font stuff, but nothing specifically about image alignment/off screen issues. Anyone else encounter this?